# How to tell if it is possible to go back/forward QWebEngineView

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

How do I  tell if it is possible to go back/forward QWebEngineView?

I need to tell if there is a signal put out by qwebengine when it is possible to go back or go forward.

I am running Arch Linux with plasma 5.9 and python 3.6.0.

Comment: [QWebEngineHistory](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginehistory.html).

Answer (score 3):

The QWebEnginePage.WebActions can be used for this.  The following example will load google, then 5 seconds later load bing.  After another 5 seconds it will check the navigation actions.  This would normally be done in your view's setPage().  The code below is just to demonstrate the API.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEnginePage
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWebEngineView()
w.load(QtCore.QUrl('http://google.com'))

def _test_navigaion():
    w.load(QtCore.QUrl('http://bing.com'))
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, _test_navigaion2)

def _test_navigaion2():
    print('back enabled', w.page().action(QWebEnginePage.Back).isEnabled())
    print('forward enabled', w.page().action(QWebEnginePage.Forward).isEnabled())
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, _test_navigaion)

w.show()
app.exec_()
```